# R, strptime, No format="%m-%d-%Y"?

Tags: strptime

I have a data as below, which I want to use strptime as I used to do but somehow it doesn't work.

```
> ic.df$timeonly
 [1] "‎01-28-2014" "‎01-28-2014" "‎01-28-2014"


strptime(ic.df$timeonly,format="%m-%d-%Y")
[1] NA
```

(hmm..)

```
strptime("01-28-2014",format="%m-%d-%Y")
[1] NA
```

(what..?) 
So I swapped the year,month,day location and this works.

```
strptime("2014-01-28",format="%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2014-01-28"
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here or how I can convert "m-d-y" version into date object?

Comment: In python3 `strptime("2014-01-28",format="%Y-%m-%d")` raises a `TypeError` since you gave `strptime` a kwarg. Try dropping `format=` and just provide two positional args.

Answer (score 0):

for me it works:

```
strptime("01-28-2014", "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Regards

JDaniel

Answer (score 0):

When you pasted `"01-28-2014"` there was a special character (hidden) before the "01" that causes the NA error because it was trying to perform the conversion on that character string **with special characters**.

It works when you modify it to `strptime("2014-01-28",format="%Y-%m-%d")` because that character in the argument did not contain the original special character. You can copy and paste the code from your original question to a code editor or RStudio's console to verify that.

As a suggestion, to convert `"01-28-2014"` into a date object in R, you can use the `as.Date` function which handle the processing via `strptime` under the hood anyway:

- `as.Date("01-28-2014",format="%m-%d-%Y")`